# Toggle event click (open/close) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a two React.js event. One is used to open, the other to close.

```
handleDrawerOpen = () => {
  this.setState({ open: true });
};

handleDrawerClose = () => {
  this.setState({ open: false });
};
```

My element works so that when you click on it, something opens, because only one event open is added:

```
  <IconButton
    color="inherit"
    aria-label="Open drawer"
    onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
    className={classNames(classes.menuButton)}
  >
    <MenuIcon />
  </IconButton>
```

I would like, that it worked here toggle. Once you click it, it will open. When again, it will close. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

`handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    const open = this.state.open;
    this.setState({
      open: !open
    });
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You can make the button toggle by first reading in the state of the the variable open, and then setting the state to the opposite value. You can do this in one function like so:

```
handleDrawerToggle = () => {
  const { open } = this.state
  this.setState({ open: !open});
};

<IconButton
    color="inherit"
    aria-label="Open drawer"
    onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle }
    className={classNames(classes.menuButton)}
  >
    <MenuIcon />
  </IconButton>
```